# Showing cloth on a tracked body using media pipe in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, computer-vision, game-development, mediapipe

recently I'm working on a project for showing cloth on a human body captured through Webcam (virtual fitting room ) ,I can track the body and move a humanoid character with it but I want to set the position of the character model to the exact position of the person,
Not a lot of resources are available for this, and I don't know how to pose it,thanks

I tried to set a position of a 3d bracelet on a captured landmark from a hand (wrist landmark), but how to do it for body?